# Why do appearances of ">>>" in multiline strings disappear in JupyterLab?

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have a multiline string that I want to contain three `>` characters like

```
a = '''
>>> test1
>>> test2
'''
```

However, I see that after running this cell, `a` equals `'\ntest1\ntest2\n'`. Running the equivalent code in Python doesn't cause this problem.

As far as I can tell, this problem goes away when there are two or four `>` characters, and also when the `>>>` does not immediately begin the line. Furthermore, it's not a problem when running `ipython`  itself.

My Jupyter package versions are:

```
IPython          : 8.14.0
ipykernel        : 6.23.3
ipywidgets       : 8.0.6
jupyter_client   : 8.3.0
jupyter_core     : 5.3.1
jupyter_server   : 2.7.0
jupyterlab       : 4.0.2
nbclient         : 0.8.0
nbconvert        : 7.6.0
nbformat         : 5.9.0
notebook         : 6.5.4
qtconsole        : 5.4.3
traitlets        : 5.9.0
```

Comment: '>>>' is widely used in function documentation examples.  So `ipython` and `jupyter` are programmed to ignore them.  That makes it easier to copy-n-paste examples.  Indentation dots are also ignored '...'.  There may be setup switch to alter this behavior.

Comment: help for `%doctest_mode` says (in part) `Note that IPython also supports the pasting of code snippets that have
leading '>>>' and '...' prompts in them.  This means that you can paste
doctests from files or docstrings (even if they have leading
whitespace), and the code will execute correctly. `